# Solving for $x$ in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Solve for $x$:

$$\{x\mid (3x)^2 = 30 \cdot 3^x - 81\}$$

Edit: I have copied the above question word for word from a grade-10 (high-school) textbook. I believe that there may possibly be a printing error as the answer in the textbook states $x$ is 1,3. From the answers being given below it is evident that the kind of solution being given is way above any of the concepts grade 10 students are learning. Moderators may delete this question if they feel it appropriate. I apologise for any time wasted. Kind regards.

Comment: Do you need to solve the equation $\;3x^2=30\cdot 3^x-81\;$ ? This looks very odd. Is this really your equation?

Comment: Start by dividing through by $3$ as it's a common factor. Then rearrange into the form $Ax^2+Bx+C$.

Comment: In my textbook it is written as $$\{x: ( 3x)^2 = 30 \cdot 3^x - 81\}$$ I'm new here and am still learning all the rules for formatting. I don't know if they might have written it wrong in my textbook.

Comment: @YunusMurad 1. Find the trivial solution by inspection. 2. Prove that it's the only one.

Comment: By the precalculus tag this seems to be high school level...and unless there's some trick I'm missing now you'll need Lambert W function to get a rather ugly solution to this...

Comment: It is high-school level. The answer in the text book states $x$ is 1,3

Comment: Now I'm really confused :)

Comment: $x=1$ certainly works.  But $x=3$ doesn't appear to.

Comment: For $\;3\;$ to be a solutions we need $\;729\;$ on the left side...only if it were $\;(3x)^3\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- You can simplify to $(3x)^2 = 30 \cdot 3^x - 81\implies 3x^2=10\cdot
     3^x-27$
- Let study the roots of $f(x)=3x^2-10\cdot 3^x+27$ (number of roots and approximate values)
- For the exact solution you need numerical method

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = 30\cdot 3^x - 3x^2 - 81$. Best way is to divide $\mathbb{R}$ into three parts. So if $x \ge 1$, $f'(x) = 30\cdot 3^x\cdot \log 3 - 6x > 6(3^x-x) > 0\implies f(x) \ge f(1) = 90 - 3-81 = 6 > 0$. If $x \le 0\implies f'(x) > 0\implies f(x) \le f(0) = -81 < 0$. If $0 < x < 1\implies f'(x) > 30\cdot \log 3 - 6 > 0 $, and also $f(0) = -51 < 0, f(1) = 6 > 0$ and since $f$ is continuous , IVT says there is a unique solution of $f(x) = 0$ on $(0,1)$ which can be found by Lambert function and by Wolfram Alpha or by Newton method of approximation.

Comment: This is way beyond my level. I am now convinced there is printing error in the grade 10 maths textbook. We have'nt covered any of the above. I really appreciate your input though!

Comment: It's a lot simpler now that the OP corrected that they meant $\,(3x)^2\,$, *not* $\,3x^2\,$.